# Rails - Sunspot filter models based on params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have a global search which at the moment, searches against 3 models.

```
@query = Sunspot.search [Person, Property, Expense] do
  fulltext params[:search] + "~"
end
```

In the search form I have a checkbox_tag for each of these.

```
params[:people]
params[:properties]
params[:expenses]
```

What I would like to do is only search against the models who's checkbox is checked.

What is the best way to do this?